# iOS - NSDataDetector: Why does url missing '.com' (http://google) return as valid URL?

Tags: ios, http, nsurl, nsdatadetector

I am trying to validate provided URLs from a text field using NSDataDetector and it always returns valid if I enter a URL containing "http://" in the front of any text.

```
i.e. http://someurl, http://someotherurl, etc.
```

**FYI** - Although web browsers are capable of interpretting urls using the above format, NSURL returns an error when using this format every time. Since I need to call an action with a provided URL in my app, it needs to be valid when creating an NSURL from the provided URL text.

Any ideas on how to correct this as those urls are not really valid?

Here is my code:

```
   linkDetector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: nil)
    linkDetector?.enumerateMatchesInString(self.textField.text, options: NSMatchingOptions(0), range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(urlString!)), usingBlock: { (result: NSTextCheckingResult!, flags, stop) -> Void in
            self.validatedUrlString = self.textField.text
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [there are new top level domains like .google and .apple](http://www.slashgear.com/new-top-level-domain-applications-revealed-apple-google-and-more-13233725/) so a URL consisting of just "apple" could actually be a valid URL these days.

And in fact, if I type in `http://apple`, that plain looking valid URL actually successfully resolves in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah thats more a browser interpretation of the entered string. But in iOS, trying to create a NSURL using:
    http:// apple (added space to ignore markup)
does not return as valid:
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1003.)" UserInfo=0x7fe7306db1e0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:// apple/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:// apple/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe7305ab800 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1003.)"}

Comment: Sounds like you've actually found a *bug* in NSURL... since we've already proven that `http:// google` is a valid URL.  If NSDataDetector thinks it's a URL and browsers think it's a URL, the problem might be in the NSURL internal implementation (and you can file a [radar in Apple's bugreporter](http://bugreporter.apple.com) website).

Comment: There is no bug. `+[NSURL URLWithString:]` will gladly create an URL from `"http://apple"`, so Data Detectors is correct. However, loading the URL will only succeed if your DNS can resolve the hostname "apple" (which is possible depending on your search domains, etc.)   
Now, Web browsers may have an heuristic to retry the lookup by adding .com if the initial request failed (actually, on my corporate network, http://apple leads to an internal website, not apple.com), but this is not something which can be done at framework level. This is app logic.

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 1304 Section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5), a valid domain name expansion (after the `http://` protocol specifier) could be as follows:

```
<domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "
<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>
<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
```

Essentially, this means that the `.` is not a requirement for a domain name. A very common example of this is `http://localhost` which contains no `.`.